# Is python Queue.queue get and put thread safe?

Tags: python

http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.put

It seems a naive question, but I didn't find the answer on the docs nor with Googling, so are these methods thread safe ? I assume so otherwise there is no point in this queue.

Comment: `The Queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads` first paragraph in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). It also sais `synchronized queue` in the title which implies that it's thread-safe.

Comment: this indeed says it, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes, `Queue` is thread-safe.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

See [8.10 Queue — A *synchronized* queue class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) (at the top)

> The Queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues. *It is especially useful in threaded programming when information must be exchanged safely between multiple threads.*