# Python Queue Thread Safe for storing and retrieving data

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, queue, store

I know this question has already been answered as:

> The Queue module implements multi-producer, multi-consumer queues, so it's safe

in a question [Is python Queue.queue get and put thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14053102/is-python-queue-queue-get-and-put-thread-safe)

However, I am experiencing a weird behavior of Python's Queue & Numpy modules in my application. I use a server to store 2 images in a thread-safe queue and then retrieve the images to process them (I have to find the pixels that contain a vehicle and then reconstruct the image).

My implementation is this:

```
# Storing the 2 images in a thread-safe queue.
def server_callback(queue, name, data):
    queue.put(name, data)

# Retrieving images from server.
# This runs a background service, which retrieves the images 
# and uses the "server_callback" method to store them in the queue.
server.tick(server_callback)

# Retrieving images from queue. It blocks the queue (for 1.0 sec max).
camera_data = {'segmentation':None, 'depth':None}
for i in range(2):
    name, data = queue.get(True, 1.0)
    camera_data[name] = data

# Images are retrieved, without raising any exception.
seg_data = camera_data['segmentation']
dep_data = camera_data['depth']

# Retrieving pixels that contain blue color.
# return np.where(np.all(seg_data == VEHICLE_COLOR, axis=2))
vehicle_indices = image_data_utils.get_vehicle_indices(seg_data)

# WARNING!
# It should print the correct number of pixels that contain the Vehicle's color.
print( vehicle_indices[0].shape[0] )

# Re-constructing the image with only the vehicle, based on vehicle's indices and a grayscale image.
observation = image_data_utils.get_normalized_depth_of_vehicles(dep_data, vehicle_indices)

# Displaying the images.
seg_data = camera_data['segmentation']
dep_data = camera_data['depth']

cv2.imshow('segmentation', seg_data)
cv2.imshow('depth', dep_data)
cv2.imshow('observation', observation)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

With this attemp, the numpy module detects only half of the vehicle's pixels. In order to detect every
pixel i need to force the program to sleep for some time:

```
# Images are retrieved, without raising any exception.
seg_data = camera_data['segmentation']
dep_data = camera_data['depth']
time.sleep(3)

# Continue processing the images ...
```

The desired image in the **(TOP RIGHT)** is constructed correctly, by forcing the program to sleep after retrieving the images from the queue.

[image]

The desired image in the **(TOP RIGHT)** is constructed wrongly, by trying to immidiately process the images after retrieving them from the queue. It detects only half of the required pixels.

[image]

I don't actually get it. I've implemented a Thread-Safe queue, as in python's 3.7 documentation. How can the main thread retrieve only half of the image from the queue? The only reason I can find behind this, is that the server's thread tries to store the image in the queue, while the main thread tries to pop it. However, should be impossible, as the queue is blocked.
Has anybody encountered something similar?

Thanks a lot in advance for reading this.

Comment: Your code looks incomplete to me ... I expected 2 `queue.put` and 2 `queue.get`. Maybe you can make this a more complete example?